# Date field shall be edited only within certian date

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have a Date field where date field can be only edited within 7 days of the date entered.

For example: if new value of start date is within the 7 days then and then record can be save.
If certain date as already passed its 7 days it cant be edited. if record is of February 1stweek now i cant edit because i have already passed the 7 days.

How can i achieve tis through validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict editing record to 7 days since its creation you can use a simple Validation Rule

```
TODAY() - CreatedDate > 7
```

You can change `CreatedDate` to your custom field to restrict editing based on its value, but remember to make sure this value can not be changed after it has been populated.